# Flutter: Offset compensation after scaling canvas in a drawing app

Tags: android, flutter, canvas, zooming, drawing

So I'm working on a drawing app using Flutter. I want to implement pinch-zoom while still being able to paint on the canvas with one finger. I've figured out how to use an `ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer` to tell how many fingers are on the screen and then use my own zoom function if there are two fingers on the screen and paint on the canvas when there is only one. Everything works perfectly with a scale of 1.

**My problem is that after I zoom in and try to paint again, the drawing is offset to the top left of the canvas and it gets worse the further I zoom in.**

I am calculating the zoom offset and drag offset during the zoom and then passing it to the canvas background which is wrapped with a `Transform` widget (*this part works fine*). Then when there is only one finger on the screen and the points are sent to the custom painter I also pass in the scale and offset that I pass to the canvas to give it the same offset and scale.

I've gotten this method to work before without the 2 finger detection but the gesture detector was also wrapped in the Transform widget which it's not here.

Here is my code for the gesture detector with the zoom and paint methods:

```dart
GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
                  ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer(),
                      (ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
                    instance.onStart = (Offset offset) {

                      //Touch Started
                      
                      setState(() {
                        _counter++;
                        touchCallbacks.touchBegan(TouchData(_counter, offset));
                      });
                      if(touchCallbacks.taps.length == 2){
                        final RenderBox box = _boxKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                        boxOffset = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
                        final boxsize = _boxKey.currentContext?.size;
                        boxLength = boxsize != null ? boxsize.width * _lastScale : 1;
                        boxHeight = boxsize != null ? boxsize.height * _lastScale : 1;
                      } 
                      
                      return ItemDrag((details, tId) {

                        //Touch Updated

                        if(touchCallbacks.taps.length == 2){

                          //zoom and drag function
                          
                          double testScale = (((touchCallbacks.taps.first.offset - touchCallbacks.taps.last.offset).distance - touchCallbacks.startDistance)+ _lastScaleDistance)/40;
                          if(testScale>0 && testScale< 15) {
                            scaleDistance = ((touchCallbacks.taps.first.offset -
                                touchCallbacks.taps.last.offset).distance -
                                touchCallbacks.startDistance) +
                                _lastScaleDistance;

                            double pinchOriginX = touchCallbacks.firstTouch.dx;
                            double pinchOriginY = touchCallbacks.firstTouch.dy;
                            double transformOriginX = boxOffset.dx + boxLength / 2;
                            double transformOriginY = boxOffset.dy + boxHeight / 2;
                            double movement = scaleDistance - _lastScaleDistance;
                            // print(_lastScale);
                            double displacementX = (transformOriginX - pinchOriginX) / _lastScale;
                            double displacementY = (transformOriginY - pinchOriginY) / _lastScale;
                            //
                            correctedOffset = Offset(
                                _lastOffset.dx + ((displacementX * movement) / 40)
                                ,
                                _lastOffset.dy + ((displacementY * movement) / 40)
                            );

                            _scale = scaleDistance / 40 + 1;
                          }
                            _dragOffset = Offset(
                                  ((((touchCallbacks.taps.first.offset.dx +
                                      touchCallbacks.taps.last.offset.dx) / 2) -
                                      touchCallbacks.firstTouch.dx)),
                                  (((touchCallbacks.taps.first.offset.dy +
                                      touchCallbacks.taps.last.offset.dy) / 2) -
                                      touchCallbacks.firstTouch.dy));
                            finalOffset = _dragOffset + correctedOffset;
                            setState(() {
                              _transform = Matrix4(
                                _scale, 0, 0, 0, //
                                0, _scale, 0, 0, //
                                0, 0, 1, 0, //
                                finalOffset.dx, finalOffset.dy, 0, 1,
                              );
                            });
                            
                        } else {
                          
                          //paint method
                          
                          if (firstTouch == false && touchCallbacks.taps.length < 2) {

                            // I used a bool to only call this only once every paint since i couldnt get the details for global position in the initial touch add part
                            
                            final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                            final offset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition) ;
                            final point = Point(offset.dx, offset.dy);
                            final points = [point];
                            line = Stroke(
                                points,
                                options.size,
                                options.color,
                                options.thinning,
                                options.smoothing,
                                options.streamline,
                                options.simulatePressure,
                                options.taperStart,
                                options.taperEnd,
                                options.capStart,
                                options.capEnd,
                                options.isComplete,
                                _lastScale,
                                finalOffset
                            );
                            currentLineStreamController.add(line);
                            
                            setState(() {
                              firstTouch = true;
                            });
                            
                          } else {
                            if (touchCallbacks.taps.length < 2) {
                              final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                              final offset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
                              final point = Point(offset.dx, offset.dy);
                              final points = [...line.points, point];
                              line = Stroke(
                                  points,
                                  options.size,
                                  options.color,
                                  options.thinning,
                                  options.smoothing,
                                  options.streamline,
                                  options.simulatePressure,
                                  options.taperStart,
                                  options.taperEnd,
                                  options.capStart,
                                  options.capEnd,
                                  options.isComplete,
                                  _lastScale,
                                  finalOffset
                              );
                              currentLineStreamController.add(line);
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        
                        setState(() {
                          touchCallbacks
                              .touchMoved(TouchData(tId, details.globalPosition));
                        });
                        
                      }, (details, tId) {

                        //Touch Ended
                        
                        if(touchCallbacks.taps.length == 2){
                          setState(() {
                            _lastOffset = finalOffset;
                            _lastScaleDistance = scaleDistance;
                            _lastScale = (scaleDistance/40) +1;
                          });
                        } else {
                          
                          //add line to list of lines (drawing)
                          
                          if(touchCallbacks.taps.length < 2) {
                            Stroke newline = Stroke(
                                line.points,
                                options.size,
                                options.color,
                                options.thinning,
                                options.smoothing,
                                options.streamline,
                                options.simulatePressure,
                                options.taperStart,
                                options.taperEnd,
                                options.capStart,
                                options.capEnd,
                                options.isComplete,
                                _lastScale,
                                finalOffset);
                            lines = List.from(lines)
                              ..add(newline);
                            linesStreamController.add(lines);
                            
                            setState(() {
                              firstTouch = false;
                            });
                          }
                        }
                        
                        touchCallbacks
                            .touchEnded(TouchData(tId, const Offset(0, 0)));
                      }, (tId) {
                        touchCallbacks
                            .touchCanceled(TouchData(tId, const Offset(0, 0)));
                      }, _counter);
                    };
                  }),
```

Here is my code for the `CustomPainter` I use:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:perfect_freehand/perfect_freehand.dart';
import 'stroke.dart';
import 'stroke_options.dart';

class Sketcher2 extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Stroke> lines;
  final StrokeOptions options;

  Sketcher2({required this.lines, required this.options});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()..color = options.color;



    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
      final outlinePoints = getStroke(
        lines[i].points,
        size: lines[i].size,
        thinning: lines[i].thinning,
        smoothing: lines[i].smoothing,
        streamline: lines[i].streamline,
        taperStart: lines[i].taperStart,
        capStart: lines[i].capStart,
        taperEnd: lines[i].taperEnd,
        capEnd: lines[i].capEnd,
        simulatePressure: lines[i].simulatePressure,
        isComplete:lines[i].isComplete,
      );

      final path = Path();

      Offset offset = Offset(-1*lines[i].offset.dx, -1*lines[i].offset.dy);

      double scale = 1/lines[i].scale;



      if (outlinePoints.isEmpty) {
        return;
      } else if (outlinePoints.length < 2) {
        // If the path only has one line, draw a dot.
        paint.color = lines[i].color;
        path.addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
            center: Offset((outlinePoints[0].x+offset.dx) * scale, (outlinePoints[0].y+offset.dy) * scale), radius: 1));
      } else {
        // Otherwise, draw a line that connects each point with a curve.
        path.moveTo((outlinePoints[0].x+offset.dx) * scale, (outlinePoints[0].y+offset.dy) * scale);

        for (int i = 1; i < outlinePoints.length - 1; ++i) {
          final p0 = outlinePoints[i];
          final p1 = outlinePoints[i + 1];
          path.quadraticBezierTo(
              (p0.x+offset.dx) * scale, (p0.y+offset.dy) * scale, ((p0.x+offset.dx) * scale + (p1.x+offset.dx) * scale) / 2, ((p0.y+offset.dy) * scale + (p1.y+offset.dy) * scale) / 2);
        }
      }
      paint.color = lines[i].color;

      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Sketcher2 oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

and this is my full code for the drawing page:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:perfect_freehand/perfect_freehand.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'sketcher2.dart';
import 'stroke.dart';
import 'stroke_options.dart';
import 'package:testzooming/TestWidgetZoom.dart';
import 'package:perfect_freehand/perfect_freehand.dart';
import 'sketcher2.dart';
import 'stroke.dart';
import 'stroke_options.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
      // const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, }) : super(key: key);



  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  var screenWidth = (window.physicalSize.shortestSide / window.devicePixelRatio);
  var screenHeight = (window.physicalSize.longestSide / window.devicePixelRatio);
  GlobalKey _boxKey = new GlobalKey();
  Matrix4 _transform = Matrix4.identity();
  final Offset _origin = Offset(0,0);
  Offset _dragOffset = Offset.zero;
  Offset correctedOffset = Offset.zero;
  Offset _lastOffset = Offset.zero;
  Offset boxOffset = Offset(0,0);
  Offset finalOffset = Offset.zero;
  double boxHeight = 0;
  double boxLength = 0;
  double safeOffsetdx = 0;
  double scaleDistance = 0;
  double _lastScale = 1;
  double _lastScaleDistance = 1;
  double _scale = 1;
  double safeScale = 1;
  int _counter = 0;
  bool outside = false;
  TouchCallbacks touchCallbacks = TouchCallbacks();
  List<Stroke> lines = <Stroke>[];
  Stroke line = Stroke( [], 1, Colors.red, .6, 1, .7, true, 1, 1, true, true, true, 1, Offset.zero);
  StrokeOptions options = StrokeOptions();
  StreamController<Stroke> currentLineStreamController = StreamController<Stroke>.broadcast();
  StreamController<List<Stroke>> linesStreamController = StreamController<List<Stroke>>.broadcast();

  bool firstTouch = false;

  bool startPaint = false;


  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [

          Transform(
            transform: _transform,
            origin: Offset(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2),
            child: Container(
              key: _boxKey,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: Image.network('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/99/a2/dc/99a2dcfa8eade86cdcc9ac747d75fae5.jpg').image
                )
              ),
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                children: [
                  RepaintBoundary(
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent
                      ),
                      child: StreamBuilder<List<Stroke>>(
                        stream: linesStreamController.stream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          return CustomPaint(
                            painter: Sketcher2(
                              lines: lines,
                              options: options,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),

                    ),
                  ),
                  RepaintBoundary(
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent
                      ),
                      child: StreamBuilder<Stroke>(
                        stream: currentLineStreamController.stream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          return CustomPaint(
                            painter: Sketcher2(
                              lines: line == null ? [] : [line],
                              options: options,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          RawGestureDetector(
            gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
              ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer:
              GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
                  ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer(),
                      (ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
                    instance.onStart = (Offset offset) {

                      //Touch Started

                      setState(() {
                        _counter++;
                        touchCallbacks.touchBegan(TouchData(_counter, offset));
                      });
                      if(touchCallbacks.taps.length == 2){
                        final RenderBox box = _boxKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                        boxOffset = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
                        final boxsize = _boxKey.currentContext?.size;
                        boxLength = boxsize != null ? boxsize.width * _lastScale : 1;
                        boxHeight = boxsize != null ? boxsize.height * _lastScale : 1;
                      }

                      return ItemDrag((details, tId) {

                        //Touch Updated

                        if(touchCallbacks.taps.length == 2){

                          //zoom and drag function

                          double testScale = (((touchCallbacks.taps.first.offset - touchCallbacks.taps.last.offset).distance - touchCallbacks.startDistance)+ _lastScaleDistance)/40;
                          if(testScale>0 && testScale< 15) {
                            scaleDistance = ((touchCallbacks.taps.first.offset -
                                touchCallbacks.taps.last.offset).distance -
                                touchCallbacks.startDistance) +
                                _lastScaleDistance;

                            double pinchOriginX = touchCallbacks.firstTouch.dx;
                            double pinchOriginY = touchCallbacks.firstTouch.dy;
                            double transformOriginX = boxOffset.dx + boxLength / 2;
                            double transformOriginY = boxOffset.dy + boxHeight / 2;
                            double movement = scaleDistance - _lastScaleDistance;
                            // print(_lastScale);
                            double displacementX = (transformOriginX - pinchOriginX) / _lastScale;
                            double displacementY = (transformOriginY - pinchOriginY) / _lastScale;
                            //
                            correctedOffset = Offset(
                                _lastOffset.dx + ((displacementX * movement) / 40)
                                ,
                                _lastOffset.dy + ((displacementY * movement) / 40)
                            );

                            _scale = scaleDistance / 40 + 1;
                          }
                            _dragOffset = Offset(
                                  ((((touchCallbacks.taps.first.offset.dx +
                                      touchCallbacks.taps.last.offset.dx) / 2) -
                                      touchCallbacks.firstTouch.dx)),
                                  (((touchCallbacks.taps.first.offset.dy +
                                      touchCallbacks.taps.last.offset.dy) / 2) -
                                      touchCallbacks.firstTouch.dy));
                            finalOffset = _dragOffset + correctedOffset;
                            setState(() {
                              _transform = Matrix4(
                                _scale, 0, 0, 0, //
                                0, _scale, 0, 0, //
                                0, 0, 1, 0, //
                                finalOffset.dx, finalOffset.dy, 0, 1,
                              );
                            });

                        } else {

                          //paint method

                          if (firstTouch == false && touchCallbacks.taps.length < 2) {

                            // I used a bool to only call this only once every paint since i couldnt get the details for global position in the initial touch add part

                            final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                            final offset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition) ;
                            final point = Point(offset.dx, offset.dy);
                            final points = [point];
                            line = Stroke(
                                points,
                                options.size,
                                options.color,
                                options.thinning,
                                options.smoothing,
                                options.streamline,
                                options.simulatePressure,
                                options.taperStart,
                                options.taperEnd,
                                options.capStart,
                                options.capEnd,
                                options.isComplete,
                                _lastScale,
                                finalOffset
                            );
                            currentLineStreamController.add(line);

                            setState(() {
                              firstTouch = true;
                            });

                          } else {
                            if (touchCallbacks.taps.length < 2) {
                              final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                              final offset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
                              final point = Point(offset.dx, offset.dy);
                              final points = [...line.points, point];
                              line = Stroke(
                                  points,
                                  options.size,
                                  options.color,
                                  options.thinning,
                                  options.smoothing,
                                  options.streamline,
                                  options.simulatePressure,
                                  options.taperStart,
                                  options.taperEnd,
                                  options.capStart,
                                  options.capEnd,
                                  options.isComplete,
                                  _lastScale,
                                  finalOffset
                              );
                              currentLineStreamController.add(line);
                            }
                          }
                        }

                        setState(() {
                          touchCallbacks
                              .touchMoved(TouchData(tId, details.globalPosition));
                        });

                      }, (details, tId) {

                        //Touch Ended

                        if(touchCallbacks.taps.length == 2){
                          setState(() {
                            _lastOffset = finalOffset;
                            _lastScaleDistance = scaleDistance;
                            _lastScale = (scaleDistance/40) +1;
                          });
                        } else {

                          //add line to list of lines (drawing)

                          if(touchCallbacks.taps.length < 2) {
                            Stroke newline = Stroke(
                                line.points,
                                options.size,
                                options.color,
                                options.thinning,
                                options.smoothing,
                                options.streamline,
                                options.simulatePressure,
                                options.taperStart,
                                options.taperEnd,
                                options.capStart,
                                options.capEnd,
                                options.isComplete,
                                _lastScale,
                                finalOffset);
                            lines = List.from(lines)
                              ..add(newline);
                            linesStreamController.add(lines);

                            setState(() {
                              firstTouch = false;
                            });
                          }
                        }

                        touchCallbacks
                            .touchEnded(TouchData(tId, const Offset(0, 0)));
                      }, (tId) {
                        touchCallbacks
                            .touchCanceled(TouchData(tId, const Offset(0, 0)));
                      }, _counter);
                    };
                  }),
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class TouchCallbacks {
  Offset firstTouch = Offset.zero;
  double startDistance = 0;

  List<TouchData> taps = []; //list that holds ongoing taps or drags
  void touchBegan(TouchData touch) {
    taps.add(touch);
    
    if(taps.length == 2){
      firstTouch = Offset((taps.first.offset.dx + taps.last.offset.dx)/2, (taps.first.offset.dy + taps.last.offset.dy)/2);
      startDistance = (taps.first.offset - taps.last.offset).distance;
    }
  }

  void touchMoved(TouchData touch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < taps.length; i++) {
      if (taps[i].touchId == touch.touchId) {
        taps[i] = touch;
        break;
      }
    }

    
  }

  void touchCanceled(TouchData touch) {
    //touch canceled code here
    taps.removeWhere((element) => element.touchId == touch.touchId);
  }

  void touchEnded(TouchData touch) {
    //touch ended code here
    taps.removeWhere((element) => element.touchId == touch.touchId);

    if(taps.length < 2){
      startDistance = 0;

    }
  }
}

class TouchData {
  final int touchId;
  final Offset offset;

  TouchData(this.touchId, this.offset);
}

class ItemDrag extends Drag {
  final Function onUpdate;
  final Function onEnd;
  final Function onCancel;
  final int touchId;

  ItemDrag(this.onUpdate, this.onEnd, this.onCancel, this.touchId);

  @override
  void update(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    super.update(details);
    onUpdate(details, touchId);
  }

  @override
  void end(DragEndDetails details) {
    super.end(details);
    onEnd(details, touchId);
  }

  @override
  void cancel() {
    super.cancel();
    onCancel(touchId);
  }
}
```

Thanks a ton to anyone who tries to help me with this.

Just in case anyone suggests it, from what I've looked into interactive viewer doesn't seem to work with painting.

This is the package I used for drawing if you want to replicate it: https://pub.dev/packages/perfect_freehand

Here is what it looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lcg3.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I propose to divide by the scale instead of multiplying by it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).